# Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discusión, site-evaluation

We all love [Spanish Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://spanish.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Palabra correcta para describir la "acción de solicitar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/palabra-correcta-para-describir-la-accion-de-solicitar)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is "Esas cestas son hechas de mano" correct?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/is-esas-cestas-son-hechas-de-mano-correct)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [¿Es posible omitir "que" en "supongo que irás"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/es-posible-omitir-que-en-supongo-que-iras)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Identifying masculine and feminine words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3670/identifying-masculine-and-feminine-words)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How should "to have been told" be translated?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/to-have-been-told)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Could General Pablo Morrillo have been misunderstood as saying "Spain does not need wise people."?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/could-general-pablo-morrillo-have-been-misunderstood-as-saying-spain-does-not-n)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Participating in a Spanish proficiency test?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/participating-in-a-spanish-proficiency-test)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why is there a "se" after the verb in "llevarse los libros a casa"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/why-is-there-a-se-after-the-verb-in-llevarse-los-libros-a-casa)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [El uso de "comerse"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/el-uso-de-comerse)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Ending a formal letter / Terminar una carta formal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3699/ending-a-formal-letter-terminar-una-carta-formal)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)